# Cannot convert dataframe column to 24-H format datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a `timestamp` column in my dataframe which is originally a `str` type. Some sample values:

```
'6/13/2015 6:45:58 AM'
'6/13/2015 7:00:37 PM'
```

I use the following code to convert this values into datetime with 24H format using this code:

```
df['timestampx'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

And, I obtain this result:

```
2015-06-13 06:45:58
2015-06-13 07:00:37
```

That means, the dates are NOT converted with 24H format and I am also loosing the AM/PM info. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading it in as a 24 hour time, but really the current format isn't 24 hour time, it's 12 hour time. Read it in as 12 hour with the suffix (AM/PM), then you'll be OK to output in 24 hour time later if need be.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['6/13/2015 6:45:58 AM','6/13/2015 7:00:37 PM'], columns = ['timestamp'])
df['timestampx'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

print df

              timestamp          timestampx
0  6/13/2015 6:45:58 AM 2015-06-13 06:45:58
1  6/13/2015 7:00:37 PM 2015-06-13 19:00:37
```